# running a command as root with /bin/su and without gives different results

Tags: su, sles11

Some background: I have a machine with SLES 11 installed. I am running a bash script that one of its lines is `/bin/su $USER -c SOME_CMD`.

Unfortunately, the `SOME_CMD` that comes after the `-c` keeps failing, no matter if `USER=root` or any different user. However, if `/bin/su $USER -c` part is omitted then everything runs smoothly. Moreover, I have run the script on RHEL5 and it worked fine.

Anyway, my question is why does it happen? If it is a permissions problems then why when I run this as root with `/bin/su` and without I get different results?

P.S. apologize if somebody else has asked it before, I have done many googling and got nothing that satisfies.

---

**EDIT**
Okay, I figured it out, I hope so.
Instead of running `/bin/su` I used `/user/bin/sudo -u $MY_USER_1 MY_ENV_VAR="/home/user1" SOME_CMD`. I don't understand why I have to use `sudo`, though. I am used to run a command as a different user using `su` and not worrying about permissions problems, but I guess it doesn't work like that on `SLES 11`/`SuSE`.

Anyhow, thanks to everyone who wanted to or helped me.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the correct syntax of the command is

```
/bin/su -c SOME_CMD USER
```

See `man su`.

You shouldn't assign anything to the variable `$USER`, BTW, because it's a system variable that holds the name of the currently logged in user.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer and the note regarding the `$USER`. However, it doesn't help. I still get different results. Without the /bin/su no error is shown, while when using /bin/su as you told me I get the same "`Corba` communication problems" error message. Any idea why does it do that?